# How to determine version of Android source code?

Tags: android, android-version

I have a copy of the Android source code, but don't know what version of android it is (I downloaded it a while ago and can't remember if I synced to the head of the repo or not).

It there a way to determine this? I've looked in the manifest for a couple of the sample projects and they state:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

so I think I can assume it is either 11 or above, but I'm not certain which one. This is what the file structure looks like:

[image: android src file structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that's the `platform/` directory. If so, take a look in `frameworks/base/api`. You'll find a text file representing each API level that's been committed -- find the largest numbered file in that directory for your answer.

Example: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/api

Comment: Excellent! Turns out it was version 15 - Android 4.0

Comment: Hmmm... the latest version of Android is Ice Cream Sandwich, v14. I wonder what this v15 is...?

Comment: seems to be an outdated answer as of 2018

Answer (score 3):

The AOSP SDK version is defined in `build/core/version_defaults.mk`.