# android linux kernel version from source code

Tags: android, linux-kernel, version

I want to tknow the android kernel version from source code. I checked at [How to determine version of Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673456/how-to-determine-version-of-android-source-code)

But this gives me 3 fields, like `3.0.31`. I would like to know the version on further depth -say, `3.0.31 –g77a6dce`

Answer (score 0):

Yes 3.0.31 indicates the correct linux version. Not sure what "–g77a6dce" is for. Maybe a branch name you pulled it out from. As far as Android Kernel is concerned the ICS official release uses the 3.0.1 kernel and the most recent jellybean uses the 3.1.10 kernel. For more information on kernel versioning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering

Comment: "the ICS official release uses the 3.0.1 kernel and the most recent jellybean uses the 3.1.10 kernel" can you please add links to where you get this info ?